# error: cannot find symbol if (ActivityHome.getInstance().mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

Tags: java, android, ads, adview, google-ads-script

```
public void displayAdMob() {
    if (ActivityHome.getInstance().mInterstitialAd != null) {
        if (ActivityHome.getInstance().mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            ActivityHome.getInstance().mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            ActivityHome.instance.stopTask();
            ActivityHome.instance.StartTimer();
        }
```

Can anyone help me with this error.

Comment: "Cannot find symbol" should tell you exactly what symbol it cannot find. Which one is it?

Comment: symbol:   method isLoaded()
location: variable mInterstitialAd of type InterstitialAd

Comment: Federico klez Culloca Sir, can I get help from you regarding this issue?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to `ActivityHome`'s documentation?

Comment: Hello Sir, I was unable to upload my ActivityHome.java file here. That's why I'm sharing my ActivityHome.java file through Google Drive. Here is the link of my ActivityHome.java "https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qsnD-pXJKVB5heU79NK1PddXXOiyYPPerxVB4lsQdxM/edit?usp=sharing"

Comment: ActivityHome.java main file link "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pPgL2d2FwDgedP05h726H8ApbWKvAQqA/view?usp=sharing"

Comment: No, sorry, I won't be opening a random Google Docs/Drive link. Let's try like this: what's the (concrete) type of `mInterstitialAd`?

Comment: Sir, can you please tell me how can I share the ActivityHome.java file with you?

Comment: I don't need that file, I need to know what type `mIntenstitialAd` is and see the documentation for that type.

Comment: But the simple matter of fact is that whatever its type is, it doesn't have a method called `isLoaded` that accepts no parameter. What you need to use instead depends on what you expected that method to do in the first place.

Comment: Sir, actually I'm a beginner. That's why I want to see you my ActivityHome.java file.

Comment: I got this error after updating the Google Ads SDK 18.2.0 to 20.4.0

Comment: Put the source code in pastebin.com . Even better [edit] your question to provide a [example].

Comment: Sir, I've uploaded the ActivityHome.java file in Github & invite you for collaboration.

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65880741/after-updating-google-ads-sdk-interstitialad-is-deprecated-how-to-resolve). I'm no expert with this stuff, but since nobody was saying anything I tried helping you. But I'm afraid my expertise ends here.

Comment: Please help me sir. I'm a new comer here sir. Please sir.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: I can't help you further than this because I don't know Android develompent. Last time I made an app was 12 years ago.